# Given a 7 card poker hand, find all 5 card straights (C)

Tags: c, poker

I'm fairly new to C programming, so let me know if I'm a bit in over my head.

I am trying to write a poker hand evaluator. The main challenge I'm facing right now is finding ALL available 5 card straights in a 7 card hand. The reason I need all of them, and not just the highest one, is to later use the straights I found to search them for a straight flush.

Here's what I've got so far:

1. struct defining a card

```
typedef struct
{
    short pips; // could be 1-13
    suit suit; // taken from above enum
} card;
```

2. enum defining a suit

```
typedef enum { spades, hearts, clubs, diamonds} suit;
```

3. method for returning 0 or 1 for having or not having straights in a given hand.
   Ideally, this method should also store all straights in the parameter 2D array.

```
int is_straight(card hand[], card straights[][STRAIGHT]){

    // Sort the hand in ascending order
    qsort(hand, HAND_SIZE, sizeof(card), comp);
    
    int i, j = 1 , k = 0;
    int count = 1, res = 0;

    
    while(1){
        for (i = HAND_SIZE - j; i >= 1; i--){
            if ((hand[i].pips - hand[i - 1].pips) == 1){
                count++;
                if (count == STRAIGHT){
                    res =  1;
                    memcpy(straights[k++], &hand[i-1], STRAIGHT*sizeof(card));
                    j++;
                    count = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
                count = 1;
        }
        if(i < 1) break;
    }
    return res;
}
```

The problem I'm having is with duplicate values of cards. For example, in the hand:
`[A - spades, 2 - Spades, 3 - Spades, 4 - Spades, 5 - Spades, 6 - Spades, 6 - Hearts]`

I'm getting this output:

```
2 of Spades
3 of Spades
4 of Spades
5 of Spades
6 of Spades

2 of Spades
3 of Spades
4 of Spades
5 of Spades
6 of Spades

Ace of Spades
2 of Spades
3 of Spades
4 of Spades
5 of Spades
```

Does anyone have a better idea of how to approach this problem? Also, as stated before, please let me know if you think it's too much for a beginner.
Cheers.

Comment: It's a lot easier to write a 5-card poker hand evaluator, and then run it on all 7 choose 5 = 21 combinations of 5-card subhands and pick the highest hand rank. The fastest 7-card evaluators currently use state machines or lookup tables to run and are surprisingly fast. I have some go code that does a 5-card eval that's reasonably optimized https://github.com/paulhankin/poker/blob/c946430b323e84ce55b1e7b7064174aaa9ac3fa0/poker/eval.go#L140 and should be understandable for a c programmer. (It's used to construct the fast 5 and 7 card lookup tables for the fast eval).

Comment: That's a great idea. Could you maybe elaborate on how to extract those subhands from my 7 card hand? Should I do it manually or is there a smarter way of doing it?

Comment: This is how I did it (in go, but it's essentially the same as C here): https://github.com/paulhankin/poker/blob/c946430b323e84ce55b1e7b7064174aaa9ac3fa0/poker/eval.go#L77 . I optimized and unrolled some loops, so there's some weird-looking repetition, but hopefully you get the principle.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great project to practice your C programming skills, it's something you're familiar with, where you can quickly check the output and it already seems you're going in the right direction. You just need to take care of the little things.

Currently the problem is that when you found a straight, you `memcpy` five consecutive cards in your hand, which is not what you want when there's duplicate values.

I think dealing with duplicate values is the main problem for this project. Maybe you could try a different way to approach this? First check for duplicate values and make separate hands for them? It's okay to use some more code instead of trying to put it all in one loop.